# NavigationDrawer double click unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have implemented the navigation as required and it is working fine. When I try to double click on any of the menu item, the first click does the required action, but the second click is understood as opening the navigation drawer. So the problem I am facing is that after double click(which is not a normal user behavior, it is a bug reported by our tester) on the menu item, the navigationdrawer remains open on the new screen.

If I click once, it works fine.

Added the code :

```
  @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    Logger.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected");
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_item_profile:
            replaceFragment(new ProfileFragment(), true);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/svg_ic_home_black"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_item_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/svg_ic_face_black_24_px"
        android:title="Profile" />

</menu>
```

Comment: are you using menu.xml or layout.xml for navigation item?

Comment: I am using menu.xml

Comment: use a delay of 1-2 sec on click event as I have done same on layout but not sure about how to write on menu.xml items

Comment: Navigation Drawer default behaviour is tested by Google Testers :), You need not worry about this.

Comment: any solutions you get?

Answer (score 0):

We always need to close drawer when clicked on any item. This will not let user double click on item.

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
openSelectedScreen(navItem);
```

Comment: the first click does the required action,--(mean open  selected screen) but the second click is understood as opening the navigation drawer. (did not get this.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing is ideal behavior because when you make first tap on drawer item it closed the drawer while second tap will make it open again.

As per your need, If you don't want to open drawer on second tap then you need to add condition for that.

If user make immediate click then don't open it, let it remain closed

Comment: Yes, but how do i do that? As the second click is for opening the drawer, and it is not on the hamburgericon, but on the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method to get NavigationDrawer double click else you can use below code

```
private boolean doublePressed=false; //Global variable

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

    Logger.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected");
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_item_profile:
            if (doublePressed) {
                replaceFragment(new ProfileFragment(), true);
                return false;
            }
            doublePressed = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doublePressed = false;
                }
            }, 2000);//You can modify this time, here 2 sec.

            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: tried to use boolean like this and other ways also, but its not working